# Winform PictureBox dynamic update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

In  my winform control I am adding picture box and assigning an image from the Resources. This works great, however I need to change the image based on business logic and this is where the issue begins. I am setting up the Image to the new one but it refuses to get updated.  I have also tried to use `Refresh, Update or Invalidate` on a picturebox again without any success. How to change the picturebox image dynamically ? Am I using the right control?

Below is Designer autogenerated code which works fine:

```
 /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = global::UnumIDOutlookAddIn.Properties.Resources.MyImage;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(616, 86);
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // WinformComponent
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.Name = "WinformComponent";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(616, 86);
        (this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
```

However, later on I am trying to update the Image, and it never updates. I have tried to differnt order on the last three lines without any success as well.

```
 mycomponent.pictureBox1.Image = Resources.AnotherImage;
 mycomponent.pictureBox1.Invalidate();     <-- Tried many configuratons
 mycomponent.pictureBox1.Update();
 mycomponent.pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: `mycomponent.pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); mycomponent.pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.AnotherImage;` ++ `mycomponent` -> set from somewhere else: is the PictureBox's Access Modifier set to `public`? When \ where \ in which context is this code called? -- Unrelated: `AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);` <- no warning from VS?

Comment: as mentioned above the first snippet is generated by VS hence running perfectly fine. Also, I have tried to Dispose() the image and then reassign .. but it is still not updated

Comment: That's not what I asked. -- The most important thing is the context in which you're trying to run that code. Also, the reason why you have `mycomponent.` there -- Fix the typo in  `... = Resources.AnotherImage;`, if that's a typo. Otherwise, explain what `Resources` is. -- The note about `AutoScaleDimensions` is related to Screen scale. But, as mentioned, it's unrelated. You'll have another question for this later...

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question then .... The Picturebox is public I can access it.  The mycomponent is called from another Class where business logic executed.... The Resources is VS folder where all images are stored. And AnotherImage is not a typo

Comment: Show the surrounding code where you are making these calls. Most likely you are creating a new form and expecting that to update the form already visible on the screen...

Comment: Not `AnotherImage`, but `Resources.AnotherImage`: it should be `Properties.Resources.AnotherImage` -- Post enough code that can clarify the context in which you're trying to set the new Image. Also, as mentioned, show where the `mycomponent` reference is coming from -- The Control's Access Modifier should not be `public`.

Comment: @Jimi the actual path is : MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.AnotherImage hence I am not getting any errors there.  I have tried to change the Control's Access Modifier from `private` to `Internal` and `Public` it had no impact.  Regarding how do I call the Image change is : I have a main form / class where the above mentioned control is shown . I am calling from that main Form/Class to change the image in the control , but it never updates ... it almost feels that the image renderers during Initialization of the control and after that it is not re-rendering

Comment: A PictureBox has no problem updating it's Image when a new one is set. No refreshing is needed either. -- We need the code, not a description of it. -- The Access Modifier set to `public` is a bad habit that causes a lot of problems, that's why I mentioned it, but it doesn't prevent the new Image from being set. -- Show enough code so we can understand what objects you're using when the snippet you posted is run. Most of all, you need to make clear where `mycomponent` is coming from. Also, if you have some Threading stuff going on.

Comment: @Jim May I know whether the answer can solve your problem? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

** I'm completely guessing as to what your problem is. **

Most likely you're doing something like this:

```
Form1 mycomponent = new Form1(); // Form1 is just an example
mycomponent.pictureBox1.Image = Resources.AnotherImage;
```

You're making a NEW form and updating the pictureBox on that Form, a Form that is never actually displayed.

If you want to update the Form that is ALREADY VISIBLE on your screen, then you need a reference to that specific form.

Getting a reference to the visible form can be done in various ways. Understanding the CONTEXT of your program will allow us to give you the easiest method to do this.

What forms are involved?  Which forms create which ones, in what order?  These things matter...